# Get Object from Dropdownbox in Java Play using Scala

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

UPDATE:

This is my index.scala.html which displays a dropdown box:

```
@(helloForm: Form[Hello], dpts: List[Hello])

@import helper._

@main("InteractionService", "newsimulation") {

@form(action = routes.Application.sayHello(), args = 'id -> "helloform") {

    <select class="selectpicker" data-size="auto" data-live-search="true" data-container="body" >
    @for(dpt <- dpts){
    <option value="@dpt.id">@dpt.name</option>
    }
    </select>

    <p class="buttons">
        <input type="submit">
    <p>
    }
}
```

This is my Hello object:

```
@Entity
public class Hello extends Model {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Constraints.Required
@Formats.NonEmpty
public Long id;

@Constraints.Required
public String name;
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public static Result sayHello() {
    Form<Hello> dptForm = form(Hello.class).bindFromRequest();
    DomainPracticeTemplate currentDPT = dptForm.get();
    Logger.info("dptForm content = " + dptForm.toString());
    }
```

When hitting the submit button, it returns:

```
[IllegalStateException: No value]
```

I need the id or the whole object, how?

Comment: If you need id then send id instead of name, <option value="@dpt.id">@dpt.name</option>.

Comment: @grotrianster I also think it's simple as that - you should put it in an answer ;)

Comment: Okay, the id property is not a problem, but when I want to get the object, <option value="@dpt">@dpt.name</option> does not work -> [IllegalStateException: No value]. But I'm sure the object is not empty, I can print all properties.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this question??????